# Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Tenho uma tabela que possui registros duplicados. Eles não deveriam estar duplicados.

Alguns registros duplicaram duas, cinco e até trinta vezes por acidente.

Preciso remover esses registros duplicados, porém preciso deixar um. Então, por exemplo, se eu tenho um valor repetindo 30 vezes, preciso deletar 29.

Meu cenário é mais ou menos esse:

```
SELECT * FROM creditos WHERE status = 0
```

O resultado está assim:

> ```
> id | usuario_id | status
>
> 1  |   1         | 0
> 2  |   2         | 0
> 3  |   5         | 0
> 4  |   5         | 0
> 5  |   5         | 0
> 6  |   15        | 0
> 7  |   15        | 0
> 8  |   15        | 0
> 9  |   15        | 0
> 10 |   17        | 0
> ```

Mas preciso que fique assim:

> ```
> id |  usuario_id | status
> 1  |   1         | 0
> 2  |   2         | 0
> 5  |   5         | 0
> 9  |   15        | 0
> 10 |   17        | 0
> ```

**Nota**: Só quero deletar os duplicados se o status for 0, porém quero deixar um.

Como fazer uma query que delete os duplicados, porém deixando sempre um registro?

Comment: Usa o `having`.

Comment: Com o `HAVING` vai deletar tudo, não?

Comment: Qual a versão do MySQL?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Poderia obter o menor **id** agrupando pelo usuário e remover todos os demais.

Ficaria algo semelhante a isso:

```
delete from creditos where status = 0 and id not in
( SELECT * FROM 
    (select min(id) from creditos group by usuario_id) AS temp_tab
);
```

Note que o `status = 0` está no *DELETE* e não na sub consulta. Caso queira que o **id** retornado seja com o `status = 0`, adicione esse **WHERE** também na sub consulta.

Você também pode ver essa e demais formas nestas respostas:

- [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/4843158)
- [Delete all but one duplicate record](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5882649/4843158)

Comment: Acho que você teria que trocar o min() por max() e ficaria melhor se fosse com not exists no lugar de not in.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Creio que o `min()` ou o `max()` vai de acordo com a necessidade. A única diferença seria se iria permanecer o primeiro registro ou o último. Sobre o `exists()` e o `not in()` geraria diferença se o retorno fosse null ou uma questão de tempo. Porém, não me parece que seja o caso da pergunta.

Answer (score 20):

Uma forma é adicionar um índice com a coluna que você deseja manter como única adicionando a cláusula `IGNORE` que irá suprimir possíveis erros e avisos e apagar as linhas que não obedecerem o índice criado:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE creditos
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_creditos (usuario_id, status);
```

> [ALTER TABLE](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)
>
> ...
>
> `IGNORE` is a `MySQL` extension to standard `SQL`. It controls how `ALTER TABLE` works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If `IGNORE` is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If `IGNORE` is specified, only the first row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key, The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.
>
> ...

Ou em tradução livre:

> ...
>
> `IGNORE` é uma extensão do `MySQL` a `SQL` padrão. Ela controla como o `ALTER TABLE` trabalha caso existam duplicadas em chaves únicas na nova tabela ou se algum aviso acontece quando o modo estrito está ativado. Se o `IGNORE`não for especificado, a cópia é abortada e desfeita se erros de chave duplicada ocorrerem. Se `IGNORE` for especificado, apenas a primeira linha é usada das linhas com chaves duplicadas em chaves únicas. As outras linhas com conflito serão apagadas. Valores incorretos são "truncados" para o valor aceitável mais próximo.
>
> ...

---

Outro método é utilizar o `DELETE` para apagar as linhas duplicadas.

Primeiramente você tem que vincular a tabela com ela mesma de acordo com a coluna desejada. Você pode fazer isso diretamente na cláusula `FROM` ou com um `JOIN`:

```
FROM creditos c1,
     creditos c2
...
WHERE c1.usuario_id = c2.usuario_id
  AND c1.status = c2.status
```

ou

```
...
FROM creditos c1
     INNER JOIN c2 ON c1.usuario_id = c2.usuario_id
                  AND c1.status = c2.status
```

Logo após isso indique qual vai ser o critério para apagar o registro, como por exemplo, caso queira selecionar e apagar os registros com maior `id`. Adicione a cláusula `AND` (considerando o primeiro exemplo):

```
...
AND c1.id > c2.id
```

Para o segundo exemplo:

```
...
WHERE c1.id > c2.id
```

Caso queira selecionar e apagar os de menor `id`, respectivamente teríamos:

```
...
AND c1.id < c2.id
```

e

```
...
WHERE c1.id < c2.id
```

Agora adicionaremos o atributo que irá filtrar o registro, de acordo com o seu exemplo:

```
...
AND c.status = 0
```

---

***Aplicando os passos descritos acima***

Se você quiser selecionar e apagar o registro de menor `id`:

```
DELETE c1
  FROM creditos c1,
       creditos c2
 WHERE c1.id > c2.id
   AND c1.usuario_id = c2.usuario_id
   AND c1.status = c2.status
   AND c1.status = 0;
```

Resultando em (veja funcionando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dDBcftx8AfXwXrd1qU4jo4/0)):

```
| id  | usuario_id | status |
| --- | ---------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1          | 0      |
| 2   | 2          | 0      |
| 3   | 5          | 0      |
| 6   | 15         | 0      |
| 10  | 17         | 0      |
```

Ou usando `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE c1
  FROM creditos c1
 INNER JOIN creditos c2 ON c1.usuario_id = c2.usuario_id
                       AND c1.status = c2.status
 WHERE c1.id > c2.id
   AND c1.status = 0;
```

Resultando em (veja funcionando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5TnNa1tgtHmFCXXgvfgKys/0)):

```
| id  | usuario_id | status |
| --- | ---------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1          | 0      |
| 2   | 2          | 0      |
| 3   | 5          | 0      |
| 6   | 15         | 0      |
| 10  | 17         | 0      |
```

Se você quiser selecionar e apagar o registro de maior `id`:

```
DELETE c1
  FROM creditos c1,
       creditos c2
 WHERE c1.id < c2.id
   AND c1.usuario_id = c2.usuario_id
   AND c1.status = c2.status
   AND c1.status = 0;
```

Resultando em (veja funcionando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q5R9w5i13RWXr61jr7PgiS/0)):

```
| id  | usuario_id | status |
| --- | ---------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1          | 0      |
| 2   | 2          | 0      |
| 5   | 5          | 0      |
| 9   | 15         | 0      |
| 10  | 17         | 0      |
```

Ou usando `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE c1
  FROM creditos c1
 INNER JOIN creditos c2 ON c1.usuario_id = c2.usuario_id
                       AND c1.status = c2.status
 WHERE c1.id < c2.id
   AND c1.status = 0;
```

Resultando em (veja funcionando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/niR3MouwrFLMeUitxMrNKn/0)):

```
| id  | usuario_id | status |
| --- | ---------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1          | 0      |
| 2   | 2          | 0      |
| 5   | 5          | 0      |
| 9   | 15         | 0      |
| 10  | 17         | 0      |
```

---

**Observação:** Para testar os dados antes de apagar, você pode utilizar `SELECT c1.*` ao invés de `DELETE c1` nos exemplos citados acima.

---

**Referências**:

- [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)
- [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/3388148)

Comment: `where c1.status = c2.status`.. daí posso colocar `and c1.status = 0`?

Comment: Se você quiser deletar só as de código 0 sim, mas vc tem que colocar o `and c2.status = 0` também pra poder ligar os registros

Answer (score 9):

Em um modo mais simples e pratico:
 Espero ajuda-lo

```
with cte as 
( 
   select usuario_id ,  
          row_number ()  over ( partition  by usuario_id order  by usuario_id )  as r
    from creditos where status = 0

 ) 
delete cte where r >  1 ;
```

Comment: Só faltou comunicar que isso só funciona pra versões mais recentes do `MySQL`

Answer (score 3):

No MySQL 8.0 existe a possibilidade de usar `RANK()`

```
SELECT
    id, usuario_id, status
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, usuario_id, status,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY usuario_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS intRow
  FROM
    Table1
  WHERE
    status = 0
) T
WHERE
    intRow = 1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7V6HBDsCmd4m9uPiz9cnWY/0

Para deletar os registros com ID repetido você poderia usar um código como esse:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE
    id IN (
      SELECT
          id
      FROM (
            SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY usuario_id ORDER BY id DESC)  AS intRow 
            FROM Table1 WHERE status = 0
      ) T WHERE intRow > 1
    );
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7V6HBDsCmd4m9uPiz9cnWY/2

Answer (score 0):

Não questionando o merito tecnico das soluções propostas, mas quando eu me defronto com isto simplesmente faço algo assim:

```
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                COLUNA1
               ,COLUNA2
               ,COLUNA3
        INTO #TEMP
        FROM TABELA
        WHERE COLUNA = 'XPTO'

        DELETE FROM TABELA
        WHERE COLUNA = 'XPTO'


        INSERT  TABELA (
                        COLUNA1
                       ,COLUNA2
                       ,COLUNA3
                       )
        SELECT  COLUNA1
               ,COLUNA2
               ,COLUNA3
        FROM #TEMP
```

Não é uma questão de conhecimento ou preguiça de pensar, é apenas uma questão de resolver logo uma situação especifica e acabar com o problema

Comment: Aí você vai fazer um por um?