# deletar os registros que repetem na tabela inteira menos 1 coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho os seguintes dados:
nota-se que existem alguns IDs que contem mais de 1 registro, gostaria de excluir o registro repetido cujo valor seja o menor entre os repetidos a tabela pode ter mais de 2 registros repetidos com valores diferentes

```
  CDDA        ID                        CPF_1         DATAEMISSAOAPURADA      UF           NOMEMUNICIPIO                                      VALOR                                  
    ----------- ------------------------- ------------- ----------------------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------- -------                                
    1693        500809150947              656********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     MA           Sao Raimundo do Doca Bezerra                       88476                                  
    1711        00029-080915              428********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     PB           Alagoa Grande                                      57418                                  
    1726        400809150949              017********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     RS           Ibiruba                                            29481                                  
    1769        200809150951              571********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     RO           Theobroma                                          24309                                  
    1773        870809150952              323********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     ES           Castelo                                            36363                                  
    1843        200809150957              3920*******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     SC           Itaiopolis                                         44584                                  
    1843        200809150957              3920*******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     SC           Itaiopolis                                         33168                                  
    1907        350809151001              08735******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     BA           Contendas do Sincora                               30266                                  
    1907        350809151001              08735******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     BA           Contendas do Sincora                               30545                                  
    1921        720809151002              2072*******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     AL           Pao de Acucar                                      22730
```

Resultado ideal

```
CDDA        ID                        CPF_1         DATAEMISSAOAPURADA      UF           NOMEMUNICIPIO                                      VALOR                                  
----------- ------------------------- ------------- ----------------------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------- -------                                
1693        500809150947              656********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     MA           Sao Raimundo do Doca Bezerra                       88476                                  
1711        00029-080915              428********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     PB           Alagoa Grande                                      57418                                  
1726        400809150949              017********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     RS           Ibiruba                                            29481                                  
1769        200809150951              571********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     RO           Theobroma                                          24309                                  
1773        870809150952              323********   2015-09-08 00:00:00     ES           Castelo                                            36363                                  
1843        200809150957              3920*******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     SC           Itaiopolis                                         44584                                  
1907        350809151001              08735******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     BA           Contendas do Sincora                               30545                                  
1921        720809151002              2072*******   2015-09-08 00:00:00     AL           Pao de Acucar                                      22730
```

No resultado final são excluídos os registros com o valor menor, mantendo 1 ID com 1 valor.

Comment: Tem outra pergunta semelhante: [Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um/166048#166048)

Comment: A melhor forma depende do SGBD pois estes tem ferramentas diferentes , informe o Banco.

Comment: Perfeito, esse resolve meu problema, porém a tabela contem alguns milhões de registros, puxa-la 2 vezes acaba sendo demorado e ineficaz, existe outra maneira que resolva? @Sorack