# Como deletar linhas duplicadas sequencialmente

Tags: sql

Preciso ajuda para deletar a linha que esteja duplicada de forma sequencial, mas não a quantidade duplicada do mesmo registro na tabela, exemplo as linhas 6 e 7, estão com status repetidos sequencialmente, então teria que deletar a linha 7, mantendo intacta as linhas 6 e 9. Segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
declare @Pedidos as table (Cliente int, Status int, DataHora datetime )

Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,0 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:56:500')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,2 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:57:410')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,1 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:54:923')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,3 ,'03-11-2017 18:26:50:513')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,4 ,'03-11-2017 18:27:06:143')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 20:00:01:523')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,18,'03-11-2017 20:10:05:563')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 19:55:26:983')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 20:15:06:563')

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha , * from @pedidos order by DataHora asc
```

Resultado

```
linha|cliente|status|datahora
1    |565510 |1     |2017-11-03 18:10:54.923
2    |565510 |0     |2017-11-03 18:10:56.500
3    |565510 |2     |2017-11-03 18:10:57.410
4    |565510 |3     |2017-11-03 18:26:50.513
5    |565510 |4     |2017-11-03 18:27:06.143
6    |565510 |6     |2017-11-03 19:55:26.983
7    |565510 |6     |2017-11-03 20:00:01.523
8    |565510 |18    |2017-11-03 20:10:05.563
9    |565510 |6     |2017-11-03 20:15:06.563
```

Comment: O que interessa então é se o `cliente` e o `status` são iguais em sequência?

Comment: Digamos que sua linha 9 estivesse na posição 8, como você iria decidir qual seria deletada?

Comment: Tá muito estranho e confuso sua pergunta. Acredito que deva ser reformulada.

Comment: não é a mesma situação, mas pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um

Comment: voce pode fazer a validacao no momento do insert fazendo com que voce nao tenha este problema , ao fazer o insert voce valida de a ultima posicao esta igual a que voce esta tentando inserir

Comment: @R.Santos o que me interessa são os status, preciso remover esse status 6 de  20:00:01 que foi criado repetido após o mesmo status 6 de 19:55:26, e o que eu tenho para diferenciar um do outro é o campo de data e hora.

Comment: @DanielMedeiros obrigado pela dica e já foi feito a tratativa, porém preciso limpar essa sujeito que ficou nos status dos pedidos, por isso preciso de uma forma de deletar a sujeira sem afetar os demais status.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @RovannLinhalis, mas essa situação me ajudaria se quisesse deixar apenas uma unica linha de status, mas preciso manter o histórico, e um pedido por ir e voltar  para o mesmo status.

Comment: @R.Santos os pedidos podem passar para o status 1, passar para o 2 e voltar para o 1 e ir novamente para o 2, o que não pode ocorrer é passar do status 1 para o 1 em sequencia, esse tratamento foi realizado, mas a sujeira ficou. rsrsrs. Por isso preciso remover esse "sujeira" de um numero considerável de pedidos.

Comment: Pois é, por isso que eu digo caso haja três linhas em sequencia com status iguais como você pretende tratar isso?

Comment: @R.Santos se houver três linhas iguais em sequencia, terá que permanecer apenas uma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cheguei ao seguinte resultado, onde que selecionei todos os registros que devem ser excluídos.*

```
with tabela as (
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha, 
p.Cliente,
p.Status,
p.DataHora
from Pedidos p)
, Lixos as (
select 
tx.* 
from tabela t
inner join tabela tx on tx.linha = t.linha+1 and t.status = tx.status  and t.Cliente = tx.Cliente
)

Select * from Lixos;
```

*E Finalmente podemos excluir os registros errados:*

```
with tabela as (
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha, 
p.Cliente,
p.Status,
p.DataHora
from Pedidos p)
, Lixos as (
select 
tx.* 
from tabela t
inner join tabela tx on tx.linha = t.linha+1 and t.status = tx.status  and t.Cliente = tx.Cliente
)

delete p from Pedidos p
          inner join Lixos l
           on l.Cliente = P.Cliente 
           and l.Status = P.Status
           and l.DataHora = P.DataHora;


Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha, 
p.Cliente,
p.Status,
p.DataHora
from Pedidos p ORDER BY DataHora ASC;
```

> Resultados:

**Registros atuais:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Registros que devem ser excluídos:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado após a exclusão:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Coloquei no SQLFiddle, onde listo todos os registros, e em seguida quais devem ser deletados. Obs. Inseri outras linhas de teste para o caso de 3 status iguais seguidos: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a0d0/6**
>
> Por fim, o SQLFiddle com o comando da exclusão: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/499f3e/2**

Obs. Seria adequado que os registros tivessem uma primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Bem... Se eu percebi correctamente a questão, e **sem olhar à performance**:

Edit grande: Percebi pelos comentários que

> se houver três linhas iguais em sequencia, terá que permanecer apenas uma.

Não tinha isto em conta no código original. Edits grandes ao funcionamento.

```
declare @Pedidos as table (Cliente int, Status int, DataHora datetime )

Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,0 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:56:500')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,2 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:57:410')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,1 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:54:923')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,3 ,'03-11-2017 18:26:50:513')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,4 ,'03-11-2017 18:27:06:143')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 20:00:01:523')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,18,'03-11-2017 20:10:05:563')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 19:55:26:983')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 20:15:06:563');
```

1) Listar todos os pedidos:

```
WITH todosOsPedidosOrdenados as 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha , * from @pedidos
)
```

2) Contar o número de duplicados:

```
, contagem as 
(
    select COUNT(*) as duplicates, cLIENTE, status  FROM todosOsPedidosOrdenados  GROUP BY Cliente, Status
)
, duplicados as 
(
    select * from contagem where duplicates > 1
)
```

3) Perceber qual é o pedido que vamos querer *manter*

```
, pedidoAManter as
(
    SELECT 
        todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente, 
        todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status, 
        min(todosOsPedidosOrdenados.DataHora) as dataHoraAManter
    FROM 
        duplicados LEFT JOIN todosOsPedidosOrdenados 
        ON todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente = duplicados.Cliente 
            AND todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status = duplicados.Status
    group by todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente, todosOsPedidosOrdenados.status
)
```

4) Perceber qual o pedido que vamos *remover*, e escolher apenas o *mais recente* (garantido pelo top 1 e pelo order by)

```
, pedidoARemover as
(
    SELECT  todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente, 
        todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status,
        todosOsPedidosOrdenados.DataHora
    FROM todosOsPedidosOrdenados LEFT JOIN pedidoAManter 
    ON  todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente = pedidoAManter.Cliente 
        AND todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status = pedidoAManter.Status 
    WHERE
        todosOsPedidosOrdenados.DataHora <> pedidoAManter.dataHoraAManter
)
```

5) Guardar o resultado

```
select * INTO #pedidoARemover_ FROM pedidoARemover;
```

6) Tratar do delete

```
delete a
from @Pedidos a
    left Join #pedidoARemover_ b
    on  a.Cliente = b.Cliente
        and a.Status = b.Status
        AND a.DataHora = b.DataHora
WHERE
    b.Cliente IS NOT NULL
```

7) Ver o resultado

```
SELECT * FROM @Pedidos
order by status asc
```

8) Deitar fora a tabela temporária

```
DROP TABLE #pedidoARemover_;
```

Código final (copy-paste para o SQL Management Studio deve funcionar)

```
declare @Pedidos as table (Cliente int, Status int, DataHora datetime )

Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,0 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:56:500')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,2 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:57:410')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,1 ,'03-11-2017 18:10:54:923')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,3 ,'03-11-2017 18:26:50:513')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,4 ,'03-11-2017 18:27:06:143')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 20:00:01:523')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,18,'03-11-2017 20:10:05:563')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 19:55:26:983')
Insert into @Pedidos (Cliente,Status,DataHora)Values(565510,6 ,'03-11-2017 20:15:06:563');

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha , * from @pedidos;

WITH todosOsPedidosOrdenados as 
    (
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha , * from @pedidos
    )
, contagem as 
    (
        select COUNT(*) as duplicates, cLIENTE, status  FROM todosOsPedidosOrdenados  GROUP BY Cliente, Status
    )

, duplicados as 
    (
        select * from contagem where duplicates > 1
    )
, pedidoAManter as
    (
        SELECT 
            todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente, 
            todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status, 
            min(todosOsPedidosOrdenados.DataHora) as dataHoraAManter
        FROM 
            duplicados LEFT JOIN todosOsPedidosOrdenados 
            ON todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente = duplicados.Cliente 
                AND todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status = duplicados.Status
        group by todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente, todosOsPedidosOrdenados.status
    )
, pedidoARemover as
    (
        SELECT  todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente, 
            todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status,
            todosOsPedidosOrdenados.DataHora
        FROM todosOsPedidosOrdenados LEFT JOIN pedidoAManter 
        ON  todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Cliente = pedidoAManter.Cliente 
            AND todosOsPedidosOrdenados.Status = pedidoAManter.Status 
        WHERE
            todosOsPedidosOrdenados.DataHora <> pedidoAManter.dataHoraAManter
    )

select * INTO #pedidoARemover_ FROM pedidoARemover;


delete a
from @Pedidos a
left Join #pedidoARemover_ b
on  a.Cliente = b.Cliente
and a.Status = b.Status
AND a.DataHora = b.DataHora
WHERE
    b.Cliente IS NOT NULL


SELECT * FROM #pedidoARemover_;

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataHora ASC) as linha , * from @pedidos;
DROP TABLE #pedidoARemover_;
```

Screenshot do resultado:

[image: Tabela inicial - linhas a remover - tabela final.]