# Como remover registros duplicados no MySQL com condição WHERE

Tags: mysql, delete

Minha tabela de catálogo de endereços tem muitos endereços duplicados para cada cliente. Note na imagem abaixo que tenho muitos CEPs duplicados para o mesmo cliente com o ID 12.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso remover os endereços duplicados onde `postcode` e `parent_id` sejam maior que 1 e manter um endereço na mesma condição, ou seja, tem que manter um 14402-408, 14403-707, 60150-170 e 81050-130.

De uma maneira simples precisaria do seguinte:

```
DELETE * FROM catalog_address
WHERE parent_id AND postcode > 1
```

Não consegui achar caso semelhante, vi bastante questões de remover duplicados como abaixo:
[Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um), mas ao meu ver não resolve meu caso.

Como seria a instrução MYSQL para este caso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um)

Comment: Desculpe @Sorack, o meu forte não é o MYSQL, mas parece que a possível resposta que anexou não atende minha dúvida, pois eu tenho que testar se condição A e B são maior que 1 para deletar.

Comment: Não tenho o MYSQL aqui para verificar, mas você pode testar algo assim: delete from catalog_address where postcode = '14402-408' and rowid not in (select min(rowid) from catalog_address where postcode = '14402-408' )

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz, você tem um campo id nessa tabela? Porque sem ele não será possível remover as duplicidades.

Comment: Eu tenho um campo auto incremento nomeado entity_id @RobertodeCampos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `INNER JOIN` com a mesma tabela para encontrar os duplicados. No seu caso será considerado duplicado se houver outro registro com o mesmo `parent_id`, o mesmo `post_code` e um `entity_id` menor:

```
DELETE b
FROM `catalog_address` a
INNER JOIN `catalog_address` b ON a.`parent_id` = b.`parent_id` AND a.`post_code` = b.`post_code` AND a.`entity_id` < b.`entity_id`
WHERE a.`parent_id` > 1 AND a.`post_code` > 1;
```

Para consultar os registros que serão removidos no `DELETE` acima, utilize o `SELECT` abaixo:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM `catalog_address` a
INNER JOIN `catalog_address` b ON a.`parent_id` = b.`parent_id` AND a.`post_code` = b.`post_code` AND a.`entity_id` < b.`entity_id`
WHERE a.`parent_id` > 1 AND a.`post_code` > 1;
```

Comment: Era isso que eu precisava @Roberto de Campos. :)