# Comparar um campo na mesma tabela

Tags: sql, firebird

Preciso verificar a duplicidade de cadastro com o mesmo CNPJ para eliminar os duplicados.O select precisa trazer a informação de codigo,nome  dos clientes duplicados.

Estrutura do banco:

> ```
> tabela CADCLI
> ( 
>   codigo, 
>   nome,cnpj
> )
> ```

BD utilizado: **firebird**

Tentei esse select:

```
SELECT CODIGO,
       RAZAO,
       CNPJ
  FROM CADCLI WHERE CNPJ IN (
    SELECT CNPJ
      FROM CADCLI
      GROUP BY CNPJ
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
 ORDER BY CNPJ
```

Mas ele trava nao e não traz o resultado.

Comment: Seria legal se você fornecesse a estrutura das tabelas e o que você já tentou até aqui pra podermos te ajudar

Comment: Utilize o cunt() para contar os CNPJS, faça o agrupamento com o group by e dps use o having count() > 0

Comment: tabela cadcli, campo CNPJ.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um/166048#166048)

Comment: Recomendo editar a pergunta e colocar o tipo de banco para não confundir quem for responder.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando `GROUP BY` para agrupar pelo CPF e `HAVING COUNT` onde o número de CPF iguais é maior que 1:

```
SELECT ID,Nome FROM Usuarios GROUP BY CPF Having COUNT(CPF) > 1;
```

Daí você recebe os ID's e deleta.

Comment: retornou esse erro: Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).

Comment: Qual SQL vc usa?

Comment: utilizo o ibexpert, bd firebird

Comment: Achei que era Mysql, coloca o tipo de banco na tag da pergunta.

Comment: blz amigo, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Assim você trará todos os códigos que deve deletar:

```
SELECT c1.*
  FROM CADCLI c1,
       CADCLI c2
 WHERE c1.CODIGO > c2.CODIGO
   AND c1.CNPJ = c2.CNPJ;
```