# Como fazer corretamente essa condição no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou querendo saber quais são os filiados que tem matricula repetida dentro de uma empresa ate o exato momento eu conseguir fazer essa consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT filiados.`Filiado_Id`,
filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa` 
FROM filiados

WHERE filiados.`Filiado_Visivel` = 1
AND filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`  = filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa` 

GROUP BY filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa` 
HAVING COUNT(filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`) > 1
```

Só esta faltando essa condição que não esta funcionando corretamente:

```
AND filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`  = filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`
```

Comment: Mas essa sua condição tá fora de lógica! `filiados.\`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa\`  = filiados.\`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa\`` é o mesmo que `1=1` ou `true=true`. Você está comparando o valor com ele próprio... Sempre vai retornar verdadeiro. Tanto que você acaba não precisando dela...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro você não precisa da condição

```
filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`  = filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`
```

porque o seu

```
GROUP BY filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`
```

Já agrupa todas os registro com campo `Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa` iguais.

Segundo você deve remover a cláusula `DISTINCT` porque ela irá remover os registros iguais. Você deve remover também o campo `Filiado_Id` do `SELECT` porque senão ele será incluído implicitamente no `GROUP BY`.

Caso queira verificar os repetidos de outra forma, mantendo os campos você pode utilizar um `INNER JOIN` na mesma tabela:

```
SELECT f.filiado_id,
       f2.filiado_id AS repetido,
       f.filiado_matriculaempresa
  FROM filiados f
 INNER JOIN filiados f2 ON f2.filiado_matriculaempresa = f.filiado_matriculaempresa
                       AND f2.filiado_id <> f.filiado_id
 WHERE f.filiado_visivel = 1
   AND f.filiado_matriculaempresa  = f.filiado_matriculaempresa
```

Você não citou se quer apagar os registros, porém existe um pouco mais de explicações com relação a duplicados na resposta da pergunta [**Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166048/59479) que podem ser aplicadas também à um `SELECT`.