# Como deletar duplicatas entre várias tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho três tabelas com estrutura similar a essa:

```
CREATE TABLE itens_chao (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pos_x int,
    pos_y int,
    nome varchar(255),
    quantidade int,
    numero_serie int(11)
);

CREATE TABLE itens_bolsa (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    player_id int,
    nome varchar(255),
    quantidade int,
    numero_serie int(11)
);

CREATE TABLE itens_banco (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    player_id int,
    banco int,
    nome varchar(255),
    quantidade int,
    numero_serie int(11)
);
```

e com esses valores:

```
INSERT INTO itens_chao (pos_x, pos_y, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (10, 5, 'Pedra diamante', 3, 17881); --repetido apenas em uma tabela
INSERT INTO itens_chao (pos_x, pos_y, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (10, 5, 'Pedra diamante', 3, 17881); --repetido apenas em uma tabela
INSERT INTO itens_chao (pos_x, pos_y, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (10, 5, 'Pedra ametista', 3, 17831);
INSERT INTO itens_chao (pos_x, pos_y, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (10, 5, 'Moeda ouro', 1, 17833); -- repetido nas 3 tabelas!
INSERT INTO itens_chao (pos_x, pos_y, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (10, 5, 'Moeda ouro', 1, 17833); -- repetido nas 3 tabelas!

INSERT INTO itens_bolsa (player_id, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (1, 'Moeda prata', 3, 17860); -- repetido em 2 tabelas
INSERT INTO itens_bolsa (player_id, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (2, 'Moeda ouro', 3, 17833); -- repetido nas 3 tabelas!

INSERT INTO itens_banco (player_id, banco, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (3, 1, 'Moeda prata', 3, 17860); -- repetido em 2 tabelas
INSERT INTO itens_banco (player_id, banco, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (3, 1, 'Moeda ferro', 3, 17899);
INSERT INTO itens_banco (player_id, banco, nome, quantidade, numero_serie) VALUES (4, 2, 'Moeda ouro', 1, 17833); -- repetido nas 3 tabelas!
```

Alguns itens possuem o campo "numero_serie" repetido nas tabelas, e eu gostaria de apagar os repetidos em todas as tabelas, mantendo apenas um.
O mais próximo que cheguei foi com:

```
DELETE S1, S2 FROM itens_bolsa S1, itens_chao S2 WHERE S1.numero_serie = S2.numero_serie;
```

Que apaga todos os repetidos das duas tabelas selecionadas, mas não mantém um valor.

Comment: Isso responde a sua pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um

Comment: Não veja como má a minha crítica, mas um erro de modelagem atrapalha demais no futuro! Isso faz o banco "sentar" em casos de muitas duplicatas. E banco relacional não foi criado para "repetições" desnecessárias como essa. Para que usar banco de dados relacional sem normalização? Essa é a pergunta que nunca quer calar! Lamber o cotovelo com SQL é possível. Tudo é possível com SQL. Algum jeito tem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gabriel, segue uma sugestão utilizando 3 Deletes, um para cada tabela:

```
delete t
from itens_banco as t
left join itens_banco as ba 
  on t.numero_serie = ba.numero_serie and t.id > ba.id
left join itens_chao as ch 
  on t.numero_serie = ch.numero_serie
left join itens_bolsa as bo
  on t.numero_serie = bo.numero_serie
where
  ba.id is not null or
  ch.id is not null or
  bo.id is not null;
  
delete t
from itens_bolsa as t
left join itens_bolsa as bo
  on t.numero_serie = bo.numero_serie and t.id > bo.id
left join itens_chao as ch 
  on t.numero_serie = ch.numero_serie
where
  bo.id is not null or
  ch.id is not null;

delete t
from itens_chao as t
left join itens_chao as ch
  on t.numero_serie = ch.numero_serie and t.id > ch.id
where
  ch.id is not null;
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Um pequeno adendo: a clausula Where do último Delete pode ser removida se o Left Join for alterado para Inner Join

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma é adicionar um índice com a coluna que você deseja manter como única adicionando a cláusula `IGNORE` que irá suprimir possíveis erros e avisos e apagar as linhas que não obedecerem o índice criado:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE itens_chao
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_itens_chao(numero_serie);
```

> [ALTER TABLE](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)
>
> ...
>
> `IGNORE` is a `MySQL` extension to standard `SQL`. It controls how `ALTER TABLE` works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If `IGNORE` is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If `IGNORE` is specified, only the first row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key, The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.
>
> ...

Ou em tradução livre:

> ...
>
> `IGNORE` é uma extensão do `MySQL` a `SQL` padrão. Ela controla como o `ALTER TABLE` trabalha caso existam duplicadas em chaves únicas na nova tabela ou se algum aviso acontece quando o modo estrito está ativado. Se o `IGNORE`não for especificado, a cópia é abortada e desfeita se erros de chave duplicada ocorrerem. Se `IGNORE` for especificado, apenas a primeira linha é usada das linhas com chaves duplicadas em chaves únicas. As outras linhas com conflito serão apagadas. Valores incorretos são "truncados" para o valor aceitável mais próximo.
>
> ...

**Observação:** Sua estrutura me parece um tanto quanto complexa demais para o que você quer fazer. Você poderia ter apenas uma tabela com uma coluna `tipo` a mais.

Comment: Muito interessante dessa forma, eu apagava depois criava unique, obrigado @sorack.

Answer (score 3):

Como suas tabelas tem id `AUTO_INCREMENT`, é possível uma terceira opção, sem criar index ou fazer join que seria, agrupar pelo campo duplicado "numero_serie" e mater o menor "ID".

Veja esse exemplo:

```
SELECT 
      numero_serie,
       min(id) primeiro_id
FROM 
     itens_chao
GROUP BY
     numero_serie
```

O resultado dessa query será:

```
| numero_serie | primeiro_id |
| ------------ | ----------- |
| 17831        | 3           |
| 17833        | 4           |
| 17881        | 1           |
```

Ou seja, os registros com ID que não se quer deletar. Note que usei o `MIN()` para trazer o menor valor, ou seja, o primeiro que foi inserido, porque a coluna ID é `AUTO_INCREMENT`, mas se preferir ter o último que foi inserido, ou "o mais atualizado", basta mudar para `MAX()`.

Dai basta fazer um DELETE dos registros cujo ID não esteja nessa query, ou seja, todos os duplicados. Para isso podemos por a query anterior numa subquery junto com DELETE:

```
delete from itens_chao 
where id not in  (
   select subquery.primeiro_id
    from (
        select min(id) primeiro_id
          from itens_chao
         group by numero_serie) subquery
  );
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwR3aj4ZY6WrrgFU4b6sxx/0)

Em resumo: agrupa pelo campo duplicado, e traz o primeiro ID, em seguida faz um delete de todos os registros cujo ID não esteja nessa subquery.

Caso a tabela não tiver um ID sequencial teria de mudar a lógica na subquery, mas o conceito é sempre o mesmo: fazer uma query que traga os ID que se quer manter e fazer DELETE dos outros.