# Melhor forma de se eliminar linhas duplicadas numa tabela mySQL (Best Practice)

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

Caros,

Estou realizando meu primeiro projeto em MySQL - ainda nao sou um expert - entao, perdão se a pergunta for muito facil.

Estou migrando dados para a base MySQL - deve ter cerca de 4-5 milhoes de registros - e a tabela nao deve passar disso pois irei realizar uma manutenção periodica eliminando os registros "vencidos".

Outra manutenção para conter o numero de registros é eliminar os registro DUPLICADOS.

para isso estou realizando o seguinte script:

```
DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN contacts t2 
WHERE 
t1.id < t2.id AND 
t1.email = t2.email;
```

onde CONTACTS é a tabela e email o campo de referencia que nao pode ser duplicado.

Testei o script numa base teste (com 1000 registros) e ele funciona ok - porem ao executa-lo na primeira remessa que fiz dos registros - dividi em lotes com cerca de 500.000 registros - estou ja a 15 Minutos aguardando o retorno (e o programa acaba de TRAVAR enquanto estou escrevendo aqui..rs - estou usando o HEIDSQL).

ou seja, quando a base tiver 5 MILHOES - acredito que sera inviavel realizar esse script.

Por isso gostaria de saber se existe outra forma - ou uma melhor pratica para se eliminar os duplicados.

obrigado pela ajuda!
daniel

Comment: eu respondi uma pergunta semelhante outro dia, com uma solução diferente do DELETE com JOIN, pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/491093/57220  tem lá outras ideias também, alguma deve te ajudar

Comment: @RicardoPontual primeiramente obrigado pelo seu tempo em me ajudar - implementei a primeira parte aqui rapidinho (localizar os duplicados) - q era outra coisa que eu precisava fazer apenas pra ter um "tira-teima" - saber qtos sao os duplicados - antes de sair apagando - e comparar com o resultado apagado - apenas por garantia - e deu certo - e melhor foi praticamente instantaneo. vou realizar a segunda parte com calma - e digo se deu certo logo mais. valeu! :D

Comment: @RicardoPontual ele deu um erro de timeout com 1m. vou revisar o codigo pra ver se nao tem nada de errado, mas acho q nao..

Comment: que bom, de qualquer forma delete costuma demorar :(

Comment: oi @RicardoPontual boa noite - demorei um pouco pq o negocio é realmente demorado..rs - Descobri o problema q estava gerando o timeout primeiro - como disse na pergunta o processo que estava realizando travou - precisei dar um "Kill" nele pra liberar. Depois disso testei 8 solucoes que achei na net sobre "MELHOR FORMA DE DELETAR REPETIDOS" - todas levando HORAS para realizar o processo em "apenas" 500 mil registros NUMA TABELA UNICA (é o delete de duplicados mais simples) - o seu levou EXATOS 8s!

Comment: e deu a contagem correta! Dividi as bases para organiza-las no excel,mas la tem um limite de registros - entao segmentei em lotes de 500K. La pra retirar os duplicados é um clique so - e o numero que o Excel eliminou é EXATAMENTE o mesmo. "Conferindo" o resultado. Testei assim primeiro pra ver o tempo - e o resultado, pq no excel eu consigo fazer igual com 1 base, mas com 2, 3.. nao da. Vou jogar a segunda base no banco e executar de novo pra ver se mantem o desempenho, mas se quiser ja deixar a resposta (so o script final) - eu ja dou ok pra ela! valeu!!!

Comment: que bom Daniel, e eu tbm uso o Excel para essas conferências também 
se ajudou a ideia, pode deixar um voto na outra resposta, e posta aqui a sua solução ilustrando os resultados, como os tempos, acho que fica mais completa a resposta :)