# Updates de registros duplicados em uma query

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, bigquery

Nesse processo em especifico, preciso alterar o valor de uma coluna sempre que houver duplicados em outra coluna, mantendo um registro com o valor original e substituindo por zero o valor dos outros registros duplicados.

Utilizo essa fórmula no excel para esse processo: **=SE($A2=$A3;0;B2)**. Na coluna 'codigo' se a linha de cima for igual a linha de baixo, na coluna 'preco' eu substituo um dos valores por 0, se não for igual, eu mantenho o valor original sem alterar.

fiz uma consulta na qual demonstra os valores duplicados na coluna codigo e qual o número de cada linha.

```
SELECT  
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODIGO) AS LINHA
  FROM `shaped-orbit-350513.DataSets_Testes.produtos`
```

Tendo como resultado essa tabela:

| CODIGO | PRECO | LINHA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1235254345 | 228.42 | 1 |
| 1235254345 | 228.42 | 2 |
| 1364656776 | 85.59 | 3 |
| 1364656776 | 85.59 | 4 |
| 1364656776 | 85.59 | 5 |
| 2222225635 | 206.39 | 6 |
| 2324547874 | 57.55 | 7 |
| 2465334645 | 351.39 | 8 |
| 2465334645 | 351.39 | 9 |
| 5746766856 | 109.64 | 10 |

O resultado que desejo é esse:

| CODIGO | PRECO | LINHA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1235254345 | 0 | 1 |
| 1235254345 | 228.42 | 2 |
| 1364656776 | 0 | 3 |
| 1364656776 | 0 | 4 |
| 1364656776 | 85.59 | 5 |
| 2222225635 | 206.39 | 6 |
| 2324547874 | 57.55 | 7 |
| 2465334645 | 0 | 8 |
| 2465334645 | 351.39 | 9 |
| 5746766856 | 109.64 | 10 |

Tentei remover os duplicados para uma tabela temporária, para alterar os registros lá, e assim fazer um join com a tabela e a consulta principal, porém não deu certo.

Comment: Tentou com LAG ou LEAD ? O Banco não foi informado não dá para saber se suporta isto.

Comment: É o BigQuery com SQL padrão.

Comment: dá uma pesquisada aqui no site, tem várias perguntas sobre "remover duplicados", uma pode ajudar, e no lugar de fazer um delete, faz um update

Comment: O lead/lag faz o acesso ao registro anterior não sei se aplica-se a este caso de duplicidade https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal! Consegui chegar no resultado que precisava com o lag/lead

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o resultado que queria através dessa query

```
WITH
  D AS (
    SELECT  
      CODIGO,
      CAST(PRECO AS STRING) AS PRECO,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODIGO) AS LINHA,
      LEAD (CODIGO, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY CODIGO) AS DUPLICADO
      FROM `shaped-orbit-350513.DataSets_Testes.produtos` 
      ORDER BY CODIGO, LINHA
  )
SELECT
  D.LINHA,
  D.CODIGO,
  D.DUPLICADO,
  D.PRECO,
  CASE
   WHEN CAST(D.CODIGO AS STRING) = CAST(D.DUPLICADO AS STRING) THEN '0'
   ELSE D.PRECO
  END DUPLICADO_2
  FROM D
  ORDER BY CODIGO, LINHA
```

Usando a função **ROW_NUMBER** para referenciar a linha e ordenar corretamente, a função **LEAD** para deslocar o valor que queria alterar em uma nova coluna, e a partir dessa nova coluna poder identificar os valores duplicados através de uma condição.